# Accessing User object in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to access a User object relation in my small blog application.

It's already in the array I've got in the view - I just can't figure out how to actually access it.

$blog->user->username is not working.

How can I access the username?

Here's the Array:

```
Blog Object
(
[includes] => Array
    (
        [0] => User
    )

[attributes] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => Gryderet
        [text] => Ja øv, så skal vi have gryderet igen
        [user_id] => 1
        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[original] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => Gryderet
        [text] => Ja øv, så skal vi have gryderet igen
        [user_id] => 1
        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[relationships] => Array
    (
        [User] => User Object
            (
                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [username] => Patrick
                        [password] => hej123
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00
                        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00
                    )

                [original] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [username] => Patrick
                        [password] => hej123
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00
                        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00
                    )

                [relationships] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [exists] => 1
                [includes] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

[exists] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have access to the models attributes directly due to magic methods.

You need to access it using the blog models relationship to the model user. I am guessing that you have this relationship setup as you have already retrieved models with relational data.

```
$blog->user()->username;
```

Should do the trick. Where the function `user()` is the relationship method in the blog model.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the rabbit trail down the var_dump, using object/array notation as indicated:

```
$blog->relationships['User']->attributes['username']
```

Comment: That gives me the error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$blog->relationships['User']->attributes['username']
```

?

Comment: That gives me the error `Trying to get property of non-object`